# How to define custom color shortcuts (like 'r', 'g', 'b', 'k' etc) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors

I wonder whether is it possible to define custom color shortcuts in MATLAB.

It is possible to use `r` instead of specifying `[1,0,0]` in MATLAB? Similarly, is it possible to define another shortcut?

For example, I would like to define,

`[0.9047,0.1918,0.1988]` as `rr`
`[0.2941,0.5447,0.7494]` as `bb` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`struct`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

```
%Defining your colors and some other colors in a struct
c = struct('rr', [0.9047, 0.1918, 0.1988], ...  %Your required color
    'bb', [0.2941, 0.5447, 0.7494], ... %Your required color
    'um', [0.0824, 0.1294, 0.4196], ... %ultra marine
    'br', [0.6510, 0.5725, 0.3412], ... %bronze
    'gl', [0.8314, 0.7020, 0.7843] );   %greyed lavender
```

Now to use these colors, use the [*Color*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_d0e541287) property i.e.

```
plot(x, y, 'Color', c.br);  %Using the color 'bronze' defined in the struct
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply put: Yes and no.  You can create custom colour shortcuts like you have said, but the only way I can see you creating these shortcuts is by associative arrays / dictionaries.  This may not be what you originally intended, but this is the closest thing I can think of to achieve what you're looking for. You can't create strings like `r` that will resolve itself to the tuple of `[1,0,0]` (... at least not to my knowledge), but you can create a dictionary of colour tuples where you access the dictionary by a single character or a string of characters, and the output would be a 3 element array.

With this, use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) object, and the key type would be a string (like `rr`, `bb`, etc.), and the output (value type) would be a double array.  As an example, let's say your array was called `colourMap`.  You would then initialize it, and throw some entries in like so:

```
%// Initialize associative array
colourMap = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char', 'ValueType', 'any');

%// Put some entries in - referring to your post
colourMap('r') = [1 0 0];
colourMap('rr') = [0.9047,0.1918,0.1988];
colourMap('bb') = [0.2941,0.5447,0.7494];
```

Once you set this up, you can access the specific colour tuple you want by doing:

```
colourMap(s)
```

`s` would be the string that you want.  I don't know what you want to use this for, but I'm assuming you may want to customize the colour of a plot.  For example, we can do this:

```
plot(1:5, 1:5, 'Color', colourMap('bb'));
```

This will create a plot from 1 to 5 for both `x` and `y`, and colour the map with the colour tuple stored in `bb`.

This is the only way I can see you creating customized string shortcuts.  FWIW, MATLAB already has built-in colours that you can use to plot your data.  For example, if you wanted to plot a red line, you would simply do:

```
plot(1:5, 1:5, 'r');
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, then you could also simply create a function `colourMap` that would return `[0.9047, 0.1918, 0.1988]` for the input `'rr'` and so on. That would then have precisely the same syntax you suggest, and would likely be easier to maintain as well. Alternatively, a better way than either of those options would be to create an enumeration class `Colors` containing a list of predefined colors, and then you could type `Colors.rr` or `Colors.bb` and so on. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: @rayryeng and SamRoberts thanks. this will serve my purpose. do post if you have any additional improvements on your suggestions.